# jqueryでソース上の並び替えをしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

jqueryでpositionの座標を元にソース上の並び替えをしたいのですがどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

例: leftの値が小さい順に並び替え

```
<div style="position:relative; left: 10px">1</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 0px">2</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 15px">3</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 5px">4</div>
```

↓

```
<div style="position:relative; left: 0px">2</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 5px">4</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 10px">1</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 15px">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var target = $('div'); // 全てのdivが対象になるのでちゃんと指定する


var sorted_obj = target.sort(function(a,b){
  return parseInt($(a).css('left')) - parseInt($(b).css('left'));
}));

target.parent().append(sorted_obj);
```

Comment: 基本的にこのロジックで良いと思いますけど、`return`するのは比較演算子の結果の方が良くないですか？

Comment: ･･･と思ったら戻り値は`int`でしたか。失礼しました。